# How to extract zip file on remote server using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, php-ziparchive, thephpleague

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and have remote server for uploading files. I'm trying to upload files from application server to remote server using `league/flysystem-sftp`. Everything works fine for static files but now i want to upload `ZIP` and `unzip` on remote server.

For uploading zip I'm using `SFTP disk` configuration in `filesystems.php`:

```
'sftp' => [
    'driver'   => 'sftp',
    'host'     => 'example.com',
    'username' => 'your-username',
    'password' => 'your-password',
    'root'     => 'my/root/path/'

],

Storage::disk('sftp')->putFileAs('zip-files', new File('/path/to/zip'), 'example.zip');
```

How can i extract now this uploaded ZIP file on remote server without writing `SSH commands` and try with same packages ?

I'm using `ZipArchive` too in this project and is there any way to unzip files on remote server using `ZipArchive` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chumper/zipper` package to extract zip files.

You can install it using composer:

```
composer require chumper/zipper
```

Now use,

```
$path = public_path('test.zip');
\Zipper::make($path)->extractTo('your_file_name');
```

Comment: I realise this is oldish now, but when calling the \Zipper::make function, I get the following error: 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on string'. Do you know what might be causing this?